# Where I should put my .so files for each android architecture in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I don't really understand where I need in Unity put my `.so` files and how Unity will according to architecture files?

Let's say I have 4 different architectures for android thus I have 4 different `.so` files each of them has the same name, it means that I need to put them in different dirs, like this

[image]

Question is - where in Unity I need to put these dirs in order to when I build it for android platform Unity will find corresponding `.so` and put it to final `.apk`

I assume that it should be very trivial question, but I can't find a proper way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your .so files (and other Android native plugin files) to work, you need to place them in `Assets/Plugins/Android/Libs`

After that verify that you have proper platform-settings for each file applied. Using folder structure like: `x86`, `ARMv7`, `ARM64` should automatically select a valid CPU target (but sometimes it's not working and you need to fix it manually). That also means that you can keep them in a folder with your naming convention as long as they are in the Libs folder as long as you select CPU target for this file.

EDIT Libs folder might not be necessary anymore:

> Unity treats folders found with a parent path matching exactly Assets/Plugins/Android/ as an Android Library plug-in folder

[image: File properties]

Further reading [PluginInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html)